# Synchronization level (executive or kernel) used by monitors, mutex, and semaphore

Tags: windows, multithreading, kernel, semaphore, executives

I understand that the kernel can synchronize processes via the spinlock method. However, when it comes down to one processor how does it do so? How does it use a synchronization object to ensure mutual exclusion?

Is a semaphore at the level of the executive? How does the kernel come into play here?

Are mutexes only implemented at the level of the kernel? They do not give off a signal or message when the resource is free.

Comment: where do user-level sync objects get their capabilities from?

Answer (score 1):

You've got several questions here:

> I understand that the kernel can synchronize processes via the
>   spinlock method. However, when it comes down to one processor how does
>   it do so? How does it use a synchronization object to ensure mutual
>   exclusion?

On uni-processor machines, acquiring a spinlock simply raises the IRQL to >DISPATCH_LEVEL - a thread at such elevated IRQL cannot be pre-empted, so synchronization is guaranteed.

> Is a semaphore at the level of the executive? How does the kernel come
>   into play here?

Semaphores, mutexes, (and most waitable objects, for that matter) are [Kernel Dispatch Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff548068%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Such objects are implemented by the kernel, and are made available to user mode applications via various functions exported by KERNEL32.DLL (CreateEvent/Mutex/Semaphore, et.al.).  In addition, the "kernel comes into play" by scheduling thread waits, and awakening threads that are waiting on synchronization objects.

> Are mutexes only implemented at the level of the kernel?

Mutex objects are indeed kernel dispatch objects ([KMUTEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff548097%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).  A mutex object is signalled when it is un-owned.  When a thread acquires a mutex, it's state goes to non-signalled, which means that any other thread that attempts to acquire it will be put into a wait state until either the mutex is acquired, or the wait times out.

For more detailed explanations on kernel dispatcher objects, as well as Windows synchronization in general, have a peek at the latest version of "[Windows Internals](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735648735)" - every Windows developer should have a copy of this on their desk, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

'They do not give off a signal or message when the resource is free' - sure they do - they are an inter-thread signaling mechanism!  A thread waiting on the mutex is signaled and made ready when the protected resource is released, so acquiring the mutex.

Spinlocks are generally not used on single-core processors - there is no point.  TBH, spinlocks need great care on multi-core and clustered systems too if their use is not to be counter-productive.

Comment: most software isn't dedicated to multi or single core systems and you won't have different versions based on that